# How do I find how loud my system would be when buying a new device?

Tags: laptop, audio, system-sounds, smartphone

So, I noticed that my dell laptop is not very loud when I play any media be it in youtube or VLC. A same video on my youtube app in android is about 5-10 times louder in max volume compared to my laptop. Even when using a volume booster in laptop, smartphone wins without anything.

So, how do I know it beforehand buying any device? What specifications should I read?

For eg: My laptop was dell inspiron i5 5567. And my smartphone was Poco x3 NFC

For eg: [This video is very low sound in my laptop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M984ihHNlp0)

While this looks like a case of bad audio at recording to me, there're many cases where the videographers are like 100 Million monthly views level and still I don't get clear loud audio at my dell laptop.

Even [This video is low in volume even when everything is 100%](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14SAn4IEAHk) But it does get clear when I use 600% volume increase app in laptop.

Edit: Even spotify app on my Ubuntu(I changed to Ubuntu) is too low volume. It's pretty annoying. How stupid can the Dell Company be? Like they can't even provide with a good enough speaker? Or what has happened? I'm not getting what's going on? Is this such a complex topic?

[image: I can't even increase the volume to loud I'm getting mad]

Comment: This sounds more like a speaker problem than a quality of audio content problem.  Sounds like you need a headset instead of using the built-in audio device (or increase the volume of the sound device)

Comment: @Ramhound I'm asking how do I know about the specs of this speaker that tells how loud and clear the sound would be. So, that next time I buy a device, stuffs like this don't happen. They're unnecessary trouble.

Comment: You have told us nothing about the audio device. Which leads me to determine the problem is the speaker.

Comment: Tell m what information do you need? That'd actually help me solve the question itself! I'll have to contact dell and poco I guess!

Comment: Different systems have different maximum volumes, for many reasons and not just the speaker hardware used. This information is not easily quantified though, and not written in the system specs by manufacturers. In order to learn this prior to buying, you'll need to either visit a physical store where the systems are sold, or find a reviewer who includes this information.

Answer (score 1):

Different systems have different maximum volumes, for many reasons and not just the speaker hardware used. This information is definitely not written in the system specs by manufacturers.

In order to learn this prior to buying, you'll need to either visit a physical store where the systems are sold where you can see for yourself, or find a reviewer who includes this information in their published reviews.

Comment: So, what software would be used to test the maximum possible volume of a device? I didn't get any information out of your answer, sorry. What do I get by going to the shop? Now, in physical shops, there's huge "crowd", so the actual volume won't necessarily be heard. So, looking at a software that does it would be good.

Comment: No such thing. You install drivers and you get exactly the same price ece of music or the same sound file, you turn the volume up, and then you need a specialized piece of hardware to measure the volume in decibels. That's how that's done. It's not software, except the drivers and the media player.